# Double to string with mandatory decimal point

Tags: c#, string, double, valueconverter

This is probably dumb but it's giving me a hard time. I need to convert/format a `double` to `string` with a mandatory decimal point.

```
1         => 1.0
0.2423423 => 0.2423423
0.1       => 0.1
1234      => 1234.0
```

Basically, I want to output all decimals but also make sure the rounded values have the redundant `.0` too. I am sure there is a simple way to achieve this.

Comment: [`.ToString("N1");`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Comment: I'm not putting as an answer right now as Im not able to test this but can't you format with `"0.#"`

Comment: Thanks, but not quite right. Try `(1.234).ToString("f")`. It seems to round to exactly two decimals.

Comment: @Sayse `(1.234).ToString("0.#")` produces `1.2`

Comment: i think you are looking for a previously asked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611552/c-sharp-converting-20-digit-precision-double-to-string-and-back-again

Comment: @Silentdarkness The previously asked question is not quite on the same topic. In addition, the most voted answer doesn't work in my case. Thanks though.

Comment: Maybe try comparing the decimal value to its Integer representation, if they are the same, append ".0" to the resulting string.
ex. if (dblVar == double.Parse(int.Parse(dblVar.ToString())) Return dblVar.ToString() + ".0"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not a built in method to append a mandatory `.0` to the end of whole numbers with the `.ToString()` method, as the existing formats will truncate or round based on the number of decimal places you specify.

My suggestion is to just roll your own implementation with an extension method

```
public static String ToDecmialString(this double source)
{
    if ((source % 1) == 0)
        return source.ToString("f1");
    else
        return source.ToString();

}
```

And the usage:

```
double d1 = 1;
double d2 = 0.2423423;
double d3 = 0.1;
double d4 = 1234;
Console.WriteLine(d1.ToDecimalString());
Console.WriteLine(d2.ToDecimalString());
Console.WriteLine(d3.ToDecimalString());
Console.WriteLine(d4.ToDecimalString());
```

Results in this output:

```
1.0
0.2423423
0.1
1234.0
```

Comment: Even though I used an own crafted solution, I like this answer for utter simplicity. Thanks to everybody's help!

Answer (score 7):

Use `double.ToString("N1")`:

```
double d1 = 1d;
double d2 = 0.2423423d;
double d3 = 0.1d;
double d4 = 1234d;
Console.WriteLine(d1.ToString("N1"));
Console.WriteLine(d2.ToString("N1"));
Console.WriteLine(d3.ToString("N1"));
Console.WriteLine(d4.ToString("N1"));
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/aCa9A0)

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

[The Numeric ("N") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#NFormatString)

**Update**

> (1.234).ToString("N1") produces 1.2 and in addition to removing additional decimal  digits, it also adds a thousands separator

Well, perhaps you need to implement a custom `NumberFormatInfo` object which you can derive from the current `CultureInfo` and use in `double.ToString`:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var customNfi = (NumberFormatInfo)culture.NumberFormat.Clone();
customNfi.NumberDecimalDigits = 1;
customNfi.NumberGroupSeparator = "";
Console.WriteLine(d1.ToString(customNfi));
```

Note that you need to clone it since it's readonly by default.

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/zW9XME)

Comment: `(1.234).ToString("N1")` produces `1.2`

Comment: In addition to removing additional decimal digits, it also adds a thousands separator, which the OP's example doesn't contain.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this: if the number doesn't have decimal points you can format its output to enforce one decimal 0 and if it has decimal places, just use ToString();

```
double a1 = 1;
double a2 = 0.2423423;
string result = string.Empty;
if(a1 - Math.Floor(a1) >0.0)
       result = a1.ToString();    
else
       result = a1.ToString("F1"); 

if (a2 - Math.Floor(a2) > 0.0)
       result = a2.ToString();
else
       result = a2.ToString("F1");
```

When you use `"F"` as formatting, the output won't contain thousands separator and the number that follows it specifies the number of decimal places.

Comment: Damn, I know I could do various tricks. I was hoping I was overlooking something obvious like 1.234.ToString("something here").

Answer (score 1):

Use ToString("0.0###########################").

It does work. I found it in duplicate of your question [decimal ToString formatting which gives at least 1 digit, no upper limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184068/decimal-tostring-formatting-which-gives-at-least-1-digit-no-upper-limit)

Answer (score 0):

Double provides a method `ToString()` where you can pass an `IFormatProvider`-object stating how you want your `double` to be converted.

Additionally, it should display trailing `0` at all costs.

```
value = 16034.125E21;
// Display value using the invariant culture.
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Display value using the en-GB culture.
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")));
// Display value using the de-DE culture.
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE")));
// This example displays the following output to the console: 
//       -16325.62015 
//       -16325.62015 
//       -16325,62015 
//       1.6034125E+25 
//       1.6034125E+25 
//       1,6034125E+25
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045.aspx) is the documentation from MSDN.

Answer (score -1):

You can cast to string and then appen ".0" if there was no decimal point given

```
string sValue=doubleValue.ToString();
if(!sValue.Contains('.'))
    sValue+=".0";
```

EDIT:
As mentioned in the comments '.' may not be the decimal seperator in the current culture. Refer to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to retrieve the actual seperator if you want make your code save for this case.

Comment: This one is broken on locales with decimal points other than `.`. It's also quite ugly.